# Inkscape stroke affecting the letters' width

Tags: inkscape, stroke

When I increase the stroke width in Inkscape for some words, It decreases each letters' width.
Is there a way to make the stroke only add to the size, instead of taking from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! I've found it! Take a look:

[image]

**In short**:

- Go to *Fill and Stroke* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Go to *Stroke style* tab
- In the *Order* section, select *Stroke, Fill, Markers*

Comment: Hello @stackprogramming; glad you found your answer. You can accept your own answer, which will tell our system your issue was resolved (and give you a fancy badge!)
Would you be so kind as to [edit] your answer to include a textual description of how you resolved your issue? Some users may have trouble viewing your GIF.

Comment: @stackprogramming 
Np. It says "You can accept your own answer tomorrow".